# Why does the English Alphabet sometimes function like a syllabary?

Tags: english, orthography, pronunciation, alphabets

One of the things that I never really noticed growing up until I began learning about other languages and the elegance of writing systems is how, in America for sure, we use letters like syllabic glyphs as well on occasion, particularly when we are reading an unfamiliar word and find a consonant cluster difficult to pronounce or like a pairing of letters is weird.

No better example can I think of than the division of some writing "okay" and others writing "ok."

I guess what I may be trying to ask is: is it normal for people to insert the name of a letter if it stumbles them in a word?

Comment: Do you mean, it is correct, or standard, or sometimes done?

Comment: Sometimes done, I don't think it'S standard at all.

Comment: In case of ok it is also O.K. i guess or more like a short form or something so it is bound to be pronounced that way, plus it might have been the case that it was originally _okay_, people heard _O.K._ and then wrote _ok_ . Point -> do you have more examples?

Comment: I don't have any examples right now, but they are very commonplace, I'll find one eventually.

Comment: @WiccanKarnak - 'okay' came later.  Etymology is probably from *orl korrect (political joke related to Old Kinderhook, nickname of U.S. pres. Van Buren).

Comment: @amI it still had an intermediate o.k. form